# efcore 3.1 does not support querying with string concatenation?

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

Is there any way to query with EFCore 3.1 by joining multiple fields together with String.Format, or $"{}" or just the traditional "" + "" + ""?

I have this code:

```
await this.Db.ACoolDbSet.Where(y => y.Plums + " " + y.Pears == "LOL").ToListAsync();
```

`Plums` and `Pears` are integers.

It results in this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Null TypeMapping in Sql Tree'
```

Is this expected?

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.SqlTypeMappingVerifyingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor)
System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SqlBinaryExpression.VisitChildren(System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor)
System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.SqlTypeMappingVerifyingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor)
System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateExpression(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
...
[Call Stack Truncated]
```

Adding y.Plums.ToString() and y.Pears.ToString() resolves the issue. String.Format and $"{}" are still not working unfortunately

Comment: It appears the issue is because y.Plums and y.Pears are integers. Adding y.Plums.ToString() and y.Pears.ToString() resolves the issue.

String.Format and $"{}" are still not working unfortunately.

Comment: There's no traditional string concatenation, in fact it's a well known bad practice. That's how SQL injection attacks occur. In this case though the expression is simply bad. Even if the ORM could generate a proper query, the *server* wouldn't be able to use indexes to speed this up and would have to scan the entire table.

Comment: You should mention the property types in the question itself, and explain *what the actual query is*. What you posted can never be true. A good query comparing values should be just `Plums==someValue AND Pears=someOtherValue`.

Comment: Yep, I agree completely. The query will never return anything. But in my opinion, it should still execute on the server without throwing an error.

Ps. thank you for the information, @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
await this.Db.ACoolDbSet.Where(y => y.Plums.ToString() + " " + y.Pears.ToString() == "LOL").ToListAsync();
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This actually works. The answerer just could have been added some explanation, rather than "Try this".

Comment: @IvanStoev I didn't see the *comment* saying that the properties are integers. In which case, there's no reason to convert them to *strings*, just use two copmarisons and `AND`

Comment: I think this is EF Core 3 bug. The original expression maps to `String.Concat(object, object)`. The later maps to `String.Concat(string, string)`. Apparently their new translator supports the later and fails with former.

Comment: @IvanStoev the former wouldn't make any sense in SQL - `CONCAT` works with strings. The values would have to be converted to strings before using `CONCAT`. If the original worked, it would be only because of client-side evaluation.

Comment: @IvanStoev or it could be an error in null mapping indeed. `CONCAT` would return `NULL` if any of those fields had a `NULL` value. String interpolation would treat NULLs are empty strings though. So what would be the expected behavior here? Whatever it is, the ORM choked

Comment: If it helps at all, the table I was querying had a row count of zero.

Answer (score 5):

string interpolation is working now in EF Core 3.1

```
await this.Db.ACoolDbSet.Where(y => $"{y.Plums} {y.Pear}" == "LOL").ToListAsync();
```

Comment: What do you mean now? EF Core 5? 6?

Comment: @martonx updated answer to say its working now in EF core 3.1