# Getting {"error":"Null TypeMapping in Sql Tree"} from entity framework core using linq

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have this linq select statment and I am getting this erro {"error":"Null TypeMapping in Sql Tree"} back.

Ill put the code below but is there a way to get more information on what the issue is?
If you need the entities let me know and Ill copy them.

regards

```
var query = from o in _orderDataDbContext.tblSellFlangeOrders
            join od in _orderDataDbContext.tblSellFlangeOrderDetails
            on (int?)o.Id equals od.SellFlangeOrderId
            join t in _orderDataDbContext.tblTypes
            on od.TypeId equals (int?)t.Id
            join l in _orderDataDbContext.VLegendeFlangeLengths
            on od.LengthId equals (int?)l.Id
            join g in _orderDataDbContext.VLegendeGrades
            on od.GradeId equals (int?)g.Id
            where o.Id == request._flangeOrderID
                        select new FlangeOrderDetailByPoCodeDto
                        {
                            SellFlangeOrderID = o.Id,
                            DetailID = od.Id,
                            Price = od.Price1000,
                            BF = od.Bf,
                            TypeID = t.Id,
                            Type = t.Inches1 + "x" + t.Inches2,
                            LengthID = l.Id,
                            Length = l.Length + "'" + l.OverLength + "\"",
                            GradeID = g.Id,
                            Grade = g.Grade
                        };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409797/efcore-3-1-does-not-support-querying-with-string-concatenation

Comment: I failed to reproduce the issue. If you want the community review and debug the code , please show the relevant entities and the DbContext.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [efcore 3.1 does not support querying with string concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409797/efcore-3-1-does-not-support-querying-with-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue after upgrading to .net core 3.1 in a code that was working.

The problem, in the end, was something like you have here:

```
Length = l.Length + "'" + l.OverLength + "\"",
```

It seems like you cannot concatenate int, decimal, etc... so you have to convert them into a string

```
Length = l.Length.ToString() + "'" + l.OverLength.ToString() + "\"",
```