# "Null TypeMapping in SQL Tree" when filtering not null using Entity Framework Core 3.1.2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

This is a simplified version of the problem I'm facing.

I have this table `DbSet<Report> _dbSet` where `Report` is:

```
public class Report
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    // other fields
}
```

Currently I'm retrieving the distinct non-null values of `Name` column like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetDistinctReportNameAsync()
{
    return = await _dbSet
        .Select(r => r.Name)
        .Where(name => name != null)
        .Distinct()
        .ToListAsync()
}

var nonNullReportNames = await GetDistinctReportNameAsync();
```

I want to parameterized `GetDistinctReportNameAsync` to retrieve distinct values of other text columns like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetDistinctReportTextColumnAsync(string columnName)
{
    var parameterExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Report), "r");
    var expr = Expression.Property(parameterExpr, columnName);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(expr, parameterExpr);
    var selectPredicate = (Expression<Func<Report, string>>)lambda;

    return = await _dbSet
        .Select(selectPredicate)
        .Where(value => value != null)
        .Distinct()
        .ToListAsync()
}
```

But when I call `GetDistinctReportTextColumnAsync` on Report.Name like this:

```
var nonNullReportNames = await GetDistinctReportTextColumnAsync(nameof(Report.Name));
```

I receive this error:

```
{
  "ExceptionType": "InvalidOperationException",
  "Message": "Null TypeMapping in Sql Tree",
  "InnerMessage": ""
}
```

If I comment out this line `.Where(value => value != null)` in `GetDistinctReportTextColumnAsync` then I can get the list of `Name` without any problem.

Why can't I filter with `!= null` when using an `Expression` I built myself, and how can I workaround this?

My environment is below:

- Entity Framework Core 3.1.2.0
- .Net Standard 2.1
- Visual Studio 2019 running on Windows 10, 64 bit
- PostgreSQL 12.4 running on Debian 8.3.0-6, 64-bit

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490403/getting-errornull-typemapping-in-sql-tree-from-entity-framework-core-usin), but it is about using query with string concatenation which is not related to my problem.